# Reg Ex validator not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

```
regularExpression = '[\w]:\\.*';

function validate() {
  debugger;

  var regex = new RegExp(regularExpression);
  var ctrl = document.getElementById('txtValue');

  if (regex.test(ctrl.value)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Above is my code with which I am validating a directory path being entered. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/wV8zR7/44) is the link for validator website which shows the perfect match for `C:\ or D:\` or `D:\Abcd\List.odt`. But when I try to run the above JavaScript it fails.

Comment: @Tushar : can you he;p me with filepath reg ex. Same problem as above

filepath reg ex : ^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$

Answer (score 4):

When the Regular Expression string `'[\w]:\\.*'` is parsed by the JavaScript's RegEx engine, it will treat `\w` as an escaped character and since `\w` has no special meaning as an escaped character, it will treated as `w` only.

To fix this, you need to escape the `\` like this

```
var regularExpression = '[\\w]:\\.*';
```

Or use RegEx literal like this

```
var regularExpression = /[\w]:\.*/;
```

As pointed out by Cyrbil in the comments, the character class `[\w]` is the same as `\w` only. So you can safely omit the square brackets around `\w`.

Comment: No point answering such questions that are so frequent. You should mark them as duplicates.

Comment: And this he is trying to validate a path, maybe suggest a correct way of doing it ?